# How to get the last submitted Changelist from Jenkins file

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins and I am trying to automate the test cases as a stage in Jenkins file. I would like to update them with check list number. I am using perforce as Source control. When ever I submit code ,Jenkins will trigger build and perform the stages. I am missing way to find the check list number. Can I get the check list number from the Jenkins file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried "${env.P4_CHANGELIST}" and it worked for me.